# How to turn a string into a binary object in python

Tags: python

I'm using this library to download and decode MMS PDUs:

https://github.com/pmarti/python-messaging

The sample code almost works, except that this method:

```
mms = MMSMessage.from_data(response)
```

Is throwing an exception:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Which seems to obviously be some sort of binary formatting problem.

In the sample code, the HTTP response is passed directly into the from_data method, however in my case it comes through with HTTP headers on it so I'm splitting the response by double CRLF and then passing in just the PDU data:

```
data = buf.getvalue()
split = data.split("\r\n\r\n");
mms = MMSMessage.from_data(split[1].strip())
```

This throws an error BUT if I first write the exact same data to a file then use the from_file method it works:

```
data = buf.getvalue()
split = data.split("\r\n\r\n");

f = open('dump','w+')
f.write(split[1])
f.close()

path = 'dump'
mms = MMSMessage.from_file(path)
```

I looked in the from_file method, and all it does is load the contents and then pass it into the same method as the from_data method, so the first way should Just Work™.

What I did notice is that the file is opened in binary format, and the content is loaded like this:

```
data = array.array('B')

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data.fromfile(f, num_bytes)

return self.decode_data(data)
```

So it seems obvious that somehow what I'm passing into the first function is actually a "string representation of binary data" and what's being read from the file is "actual binary data".

I tried using bytearray like this to "binaryfy" the string:

```
mms = MMSMessage.from_data(bytearray(split[1].strip(), "utf8"))

but that throws the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decodepdu.py", line 41, in <module>
    mms = MMSMessage.from_data(bytearray(split[1].strip(), "utf8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

which seems weird because it's using an 'ascii' codec but I specified utf8 encoding.

Anyway at this point I'm in over my head because I'm not really all that familiar with python, so for now I'm just writing the content to a temporary file but I would really rather not.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: What you're calling `data` is a string. The `MMSMessage.from_data` method seems to expect a bytes-like object. Have you tried `data.encode()`? You could also construct a `io.BytesIO` object from your string. It behaves in a file-like way, without you having to actually save any files.

Comment: Are you sure the error was triggered by the bytearray(...) call and not further down the call chain? Look at the full traceback or, if you can't for some reason, split that line into two, storing the byte array in a temp variable, so that you can see what triggers the exception.

Comment: @PaulM. okay I looked up "bytes-like object" and it says "array.array" is one of those. I looked at the "from_file" method and it does use an array.array('B') which seems like it's an array of bytes maybe. I have expanded the code above to include the array.array('B') initialisation. I noticed it uses the array.array().fromfile method, I looked up and found that array.array() also has "fromstring", so I tried initialising a new array.array('B') and then passing the content into the fromstring method and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks to Paul M. in the comments, this works:

```
data = buf.getvalue()
split = data.split("\r\n\r\n");
pdu = array.array('B');
pdu.fromstring(split[1]);
mms = MMSMessage.from_data(pdu);
```